# when I input BillyJoel, it prints BillyJoel, when I input Billy it prints out only a B, how do I Fix?

Tags: c

when i print ./run BillyJoel
It prints

Billy

Joel

when i print ./run Billy
It only prints a "B"

how do I get it to print
"Only first name entered"

"Billy"

```
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char name[80], first[40], last[40];
    int i,j,k;
    printf("Enter your first and last name or just your first name ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    for (i = 1; i < strlen(name); i++){
        if (name[i] >= 65 && name[i] <= 90){
            j = i - 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (k = 0; k <= j; k++)
        first[k] = name[k];
    first[k] = '\0';
    for (j = 0;name[i]!='\0'; j++){
        last[j] = name[i];
        i++;
    }
    last[j] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", first);
    printf("%s\n", last);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `scanf("%s", name)` will only ever read one word with the end marked by white space (blank, tab, newline).  You'd probably do better reading a whole line with `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`.  Then you can parse it (split it) however you want — possibly using `sscanf()`.  Don't write 65 where you mean `'A'` or `90` where you mean `'Z'`.